# Need optimization advice

Tags: fpga, vhdl

I'm developing an application with goal to achieve maximum throughput from device. By throughput i mean maximum amount of "cores" running at max frequency.

So, we have: Virtex-6 XC6VLX240T, ISE 14.4

Main module: UART, data prepare and data collection from submodules

Each submodule connects to main module via interface:

```
(
        clock              : in std_logic;
        reset              : in std_logic;

        data_input         : in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
        data_flag          : in std_logic;

        done               : out std_logic;
        data_ready         : out std_logic
)
```

Regarding device resources we can fit around 230 cores + main module to fully utilize device capacity.

Main module + 64 cores run perfectly fine at 200 MHz. 128 cores - synthesizer says max achievable frequency around 140 MHz, which is not good. I looked at floorplan in PlanAhead: all of my critical paths are the lines connecting main module and submodules.

I tried to register these lines:

```
signal reset_corebuf              : std_logic_vector(NCORES - 1 downto 0);
signal data_input_corebuf         : std_logic_vector((NCORES * 32) - 1 downto 0);
signal data_flag_corebuf          : std_logic_vector(NCORES - 1 downto 0);
signal done_corebuf               : std_logic_vector(NCORES - 1 downto 0);
signal data_ready_corebuf         : std_logic_vector(NCORES - 1 downto 0);

process (clk)
begin
    if (rising_edge(clk)) then
        for i in 0 to NCORES - 1 loop
            reset_corebuf(i) <= reset;
            data_input_corebuf((i + 1) * 32 - 1 downto i * 32) <= core_data;
            data_flag_corebuf(i) <= data_core_flag(i);

            core_done(i) <= done_corebuf(i);
            data_core_ready(i) <= data_ready_corebuf(i);
        end loop;
    end if;
end process;
```

and nothing changed, but i feel that should be better, right ?

What am i doing wrong and what the general idea to optimize such architecture ?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29222127/need-optimization-advice

Comment: My bad, sorry. I deleted stackoverflow duplicate.

Comment: Appears off topic for Stackoverflow, can't reproduce the problem from available code. It's not otherwise 'illegal' to post to more than one Stack Exchange site.

Comment: I'd guess you're seeing routing delays from all these cores to the Main 'module' You're off by about 2 ns. (The VHDL standard only mentions the word 'module' once, and it's not applicable here and like erroneous in the standard - dating from 1987. See IEEE Std 1076-2008 15.9 Comments "Furthermore, comments do not influence the execution of a simulation module;...", likely should say "influence the simulation of an elaborated design hierarchy". VHDL got no modules.)

Comment: Yes, you right, that's the routing delays from cores to.. let's name it "main core" or what's the right word ?

Comment: Do you have the "equivalent_register_removal" synthesis option active? It is embedded in the "Xilinx Specific Options" of the synthesis properties.

Comment: **block**: The representation of a portion of the hierarchy of a design.

Comment: How come 128 cores (NCORES?) sounds like a fanout issue? Having read through ***Virtex-6 FPGA Routing Optimization Design Techniques***, ([WP381](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/white_papers/wp381_V6_Routing_Optimization.pdf)) I could wonder how well Xilinx manages rise and fall times - "See if they are higher fanout, and evaluate the placement of all of the loads.
If the loads are placed far away from each other, consider area grouping them closer together or minimizing the fanout on the net." Page 4., c., para 2.

Comment: Page 7., 8., b., " If running XST, disable “equivalent register removal”. By default, it is set to YES".  (Methinks Jonathan knows what he's talking about, the voice of experience).

Comment: I think the questions title would benefit from an edit. Currently its not much better than "I have a question".

Comment: Note that 128 cores with 140 MHz is still better than 64 cores with 200 MHz.

Answer (score 1):

I've had some success using a similar technique to what you have proposed above, which is to essentially create multiple registered duplicates of the high-fanout nets. You can use one per destination as you have, or what I have done in some cases is to duplicate them so that there is one registered duplicate for every n destinations.

In theory, you should be able to simply register the signals once, and the tools should automatically duplicate this register to solve routing issues caused by high fan out during optimisation. Unfortunately my experience is that this does not happen. Even worse, the synthesis tool can by default delete any duplicates you have tried to manually create, in order to reduce logic usage!

So to answer your question, my advice is to turn off equivalent register removal in the Xilinx-specific synthesis options, or to place a `keep` constraint on your duplicated high-fanout signals.

Note the potential downside of turning off equivalent register removal is that any code that is written in a high level manor, under the assumption that duplicate registers will be optimised away, could start using a lot more resources.